# Solving a first order non-linear homogenous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Original problem is:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3y + x}{3x + y}
$$

After substituting multiplying the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{x}$ and substituting $v = \frac{y}{x}$ I arrived at

$$
\frac{1}{x}dx = \frac{3+v}{1-v^2}dv 
$$

After integrating initially using partial fractions and getting:

$$
\ln |x| = \frac{3}{2}\ln(1+v) - \frac{3}{2}\ln(1-u) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(1-v^2) 
$$

I went to wolfram alpha and found the simplified version of the integral was

$$
\ln |x| = \ln(1+v) - 2\ln(1-v)
$$

Which made my final answer without solving for y

$$
\ln|x| = \ln\frac{1+\frac{y}{x}}{\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}
$$

The answer in the textbook, however, was:

$$
\ln|x| = \ln \left(\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right) \left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)
$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have a sign problem. Make sure of your derivations.

Comment: It seems that you are correct and that the texbook is wrong (not first time, be sure !).

Comment: I'd recommend you not to use WA when solving problems. It's a bad habit

Comment: @AvZ I used it as a last resort because when disputing the textbook (and also before coming here) I wanted to make sure I was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3y + x}{3x + y}\stackrel{v=y/x}\implies x\frac{dv}{dx}+v=\frac{3v+1}{3+v}\implies x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1-v^2}{3+v}\implies \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{v+3}{1-v^2}dv$$
Then partial fractions:
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\left(\frac{2}{1-v}+\frac{1}{1+v}\right )dv$$
So:
$$\ln|x|=-2\ln|1-v|+\ln|1+v|+c$$
So:
$$x=k\frac{1+v}{(1-v)^2}=k\frac{1+y/x}{(1-y/x)^2}$$
So your answer is correct, as a proof I can present a maxima output:
[image]

Converting last output:
$$k'x=\frac{1+y/x}{(1-y/x)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Up to $$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{3+v}{1-v^2}dv$$ everything is correct but partial fraction decomposition leads to $$\frac{dx}{x}=\left(\frac{2}{1-v}+\frac{1}{1+v}\right )dv$$ I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: integrating we get $\ln x=2\ln|1-v|/(-1)+\ln|1+v|$ dividing by constant term the coefficient of v i.e. -1 we get the same as OP!

Comment: @ADG. You are right ! I should delete my answer. By the way, did you change your answer in the last 10 minutes ?

Comment: Yes was editing it; no need delete it; just another convincing proof that OP did correctly.